# Consider $\vec{y}'(t) = A\vec{y}(t)$ with some conditions, find the matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider $\vec{y}'(t) = A\vec{y}(t)$, where $A$ is a real $2 \times 2$ constant matrix with repeated eigenvalues. 
>   Assume that phase plane solution trajectories have horizontal tangents on the line $y_2 = 2y_1$ and vertical tangents on the line $y_1 = 0$, that the matrix $A$ has a nonzero repeated eigenvalue, and that $a_{21} = -4$. Find $A$.

I'm looking to get pointed in the right direction.

I tried something like

$a_{11}y_1+a_{12}y_2=0$

$a_{21}y_1+a_{22}y_2=0$

And found $a_{22}= 2$.

What next? Is this even the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing pretty much the right thing. The horizontal tangents condition was
$$\frac{dy_2}{dt}=a_{21}y_1+a_{22}y_2=-4y_1+a_{22}\cdot2y_1=0$$
So you got $a_{22}=2$. Then the vertical tangents condition is
$$\frac{dy_1}{dt}=a_{11}y_1+a_{12}y_2=a_{12}y_2=0$$
So that $a_{12}=0$. Now your matrix looks like
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&0\\-4&2\end{bmatrix}$$
Since the matirx $A$ is lower triangular, you can read off the eigenvalues from the diagonal, and since they are repeated, $a_{11}=\dots$