# Finding A in ${\bf y}' =A {\bf y}$ from the phase line solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the linear system ${\bf y}' =A {\bf y}$, where $A$ is a real $2×2$ constant matrix with repeated eigenvalues. Use the given information to determine the matrix $A$.
>
> Phase plane solution trajectories have horizontal tangents on the line $y_2=2y_1$ and vertical tangents on the line $y_1=0$. The matrix $A$ has a nonzero repeated eigenvalue and $a_{21}=−5$.

I was working on this problem for my Differential Equations class. I began the process with

$a_{11}y_1+a_{12}y_2=0
$

$a_{21}y_1+a_{22}y_2=0
$

I plugged $-5$ in for $a_{21}$, used the the fact $y_2=2 y_1$ to find the $a_{22}=2.5$. From there I solved for $a_{12}$ by the fact $y_1=0$ so $a_{12}=0$. But I can't figure out how'd you solve for $a_{11}$. I saw a similar question on this stack exchange, but they stopped talking before getting to this bit. I also saw the repeated eigen values part and realized that I could solve $a_{11}$ by finding the eigenvalues and figuring what value of $a_{11}$ could lead to a single eigen value (this'd be a value that makes the discriminant $0$ when solving for the eigen values). But I got it wrong. Is this how I'm meant to be solving it?

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805294/consider-vecyt-a-vecyt-with-some-conditions-find-the-matrix-a), except that the other question has numbers that make it better formed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consider $\vec{y}'(t) = A\vec{y}(t)$ with some conditions, find the matrix $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805294/consider-vecyt-a-vecyt-with-some-conditions-find-the-matrix-a)

Comment: Yes I saw that one, however, I couldn't understand the last few lines when they were referring to finding a11. And then the explanation cuts off. That's why I asked this

Comment: @user3186491 It follows from the eigenvalues of $A$.Indeed, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(a_{11}-X)(2-X)$, so that $a_{11} = 2$ is the only possibility to have a repeated eigenvalue.